# How can I include a local package dependency in my docker build?

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, turborepo

I have a turborepo monorepo, using yarn workspaces which looks like this

├── packages

│   ├── server-common

├── services

│   ├── auth

Services/auth is dependant on packages/server-common and using yarn workspaces, imports it like so

```
  "dependencies": {
    "server-common": "*",
  }
```

I want to build a docker image out of services/auth, however packages/server-common is not hosted on npm, it is a local package.

Hence, when building the following dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

It fails on the yarn install stage, because docker is trying to download a package from npm, when it is a local package.

```
#9 8.441 error Received malformed response from registry for "server-common". The registry may be down.
```

Is there a way that this local package can be included in the docker build?

Comment: Did you find any solution? i've been experiencing some docker-related pains myself and there's just crickets on every turborepo related post out there sadly.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to copy your local package into the container.

```
FROM node:16-alpine

COPY path/to/server-common .
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn install --production
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

```json
"dependencies": {
    "server-common": "file:../server-common"
}
```

Comment: Inelegant because you end up with two copies of server-common on the server. But at least it should work.

Comment: @hartshoj You should be able to resolve that by adding another build stage to the docker file. One stage for installing/building and one for production where you only copy the build output (or the node_modules depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue using `yarn workspaces`. I ended up just building the package I want to use in my app and reproducing the directory setup to support symlinks used by yarn workspaces.

This was my setup:

**PROJECT ROOT**

```
- package.json
- packages/
  - common/ (directory I want to install in either app1/app2)
  - app1/
  - app2/
- Dockerfile
```

***package.json***

```
{
   "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:common": "yarn workspace @monorepo/common build",
    "build:app1": "yarn workspace @monorepo/app1 build",
    "start:app1": "yarn workspace @monorepo/app start",
    "build:app2": "yarn workspace @monorepo/app2 build",
    "start:app2": "yarn workspace @monorepo/app2 start",
  },
  "name": "monorepo",
}
```

***Dockerfile***

```
ARG BUILD_CONTEXT

FROM node:18.12.0-alpine AS builder
ARG BUILD_CONTEXT
ENV ENV_BUILD_CONTEXT=$BUILD_CONTEXT
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT} /usr/app/packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT}
COPY packages/common /usr/app/packages/common
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build:common
RUN yarn run build:${BUILD_CONTEXT}


FROM node:18.12.0-alpine AS final
ARG BUILD_CONTEXT
ENV ENV_BUILD_CONTEXT=$BUILD_CONTEXT
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY --from=builder ./usr/app/packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT}/build ./packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT}/build
COPY --from=builder ./usr/app/packages/common/build ./packages/common/build
COPY --from=builder ./usr/app/packages/common/package.json ./packages/common
COPY packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT}/package.json ./packages/${BUILD_CONTEXT}
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD yarn run start:${ENV_BUILD_CONTEXT}
```

If you want to build an image for `app1`, simply run this: `docker build -t image-name --build-arg BUILD_CONTEXT=app1 -f Dockerfile .`

This should work.

***NB.*** For this to work, you want your script names to match up with the names of the packages.

Hope this helps.